# Program to pull data from an Oracle database

Tags: python, console, oracle

EDIT: I should clarify that this program currently works as intended (not looking for help making it work); I just want to understand what I could have done better in terms of design.

---

I work on a team that tackles ad-hoc analyses and, as such, doesn't put much care into proper formatting or design. That being said, I wrote a quick program to pull data from an Oracle db to help some other teams (and to get practice) and would love some feedback.

All it needs to do is (at the command line) ask a user for credentials, ask a user for a query, and then write the oracle data out as a csv to be sent in an email. I'm mainly looking for the big issues: should I have used an OOP approach? Is user input obtained improperly? Error handling messed up? Any weird, glaring errors no self-respecting programmer would ever commit? Anything constructive for someone with no academic background in computer science, but reasonable practical comfort with it. I just need to know how to progress.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
from termcolor import colored
import getpass
from datetime import datetime
import os
import subprocess

os.environ['ORACLE_HOME'] = '/apps/oracle/product/12.1.0.2'
os.environ['ORACLE_SID'] = 'ORCL'

# print header
tool_name = '##   ORACLE DATA PULL TOOL   ##'
print('\n##', '=' * (len(tool_name) - 4), '##', sep='')
print(tool_name)
print('##', '=' * (len(tool_name) - 4), '##\n', sep='')


def conn_oracle():
    # -------------------------------------------
    # attempt connection to Oracle, close program if connection fails more than once

    for tries in range(0, 2):
        try:
            conn_oracle.oracle_ntid = input("Please enter Oracle user ID: ")
            oracle_pw = getpass.getpass("Please enter Oracle password: ")
            con = cx_Oracle.connect(
                conn_oracle.oracle_ntid.upper(), oracle_pw, "connection") #changed
        except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError:
            print(colored("Credentials incorrect, please try again.\n", "red"))
            continue
        else:
            query_oracle(con)
            break
    else:
        print(colored("\nCONNECTION FAILED TWICE, SHUTTING DOWN TO PREVENT ORACLE ACCOUNT FROM LOCKING.", "red"))


def query_oracle(con):
    # -------------------------------------------
    # get query and test size

    for tries in range(0, 4):
        try:
            query_lines = []
            print("Enter/paste SQL query, terminated by a semicolon: ")
            while True:
                line = input()
                if ';' in line:
                    query_lines.append(line)
                    break
                else:
                    query_lines.append(line)

            query_lines_2 = ' '.join(query_lines)
            query = ' '.join(query_lines_2.split())

            check_size = "select count(*) from (" + \
                query.replace(';', '') + ")"

            check_size_df = pd.read_sql_query(check_size, con)

            if int(check_size_df.max().values[0]) > 1000000:
                print(colored("Desired data is more than 1,000,000 rows - trim query or request a sqoop.", "red"))
            else:
                oracle_df = pd.read_sql_query(query.replace(';', ''), con)
                write_df(oracle_df)

        except BaseException:  # should catch a legitimate error here...
            print(colored("SQL query contains one or more errors - please try again.\n", "red"))
            continue
        else:
            break
    else:
        print(colored("Final query attempt failed, shutting down.", "red"))


def write_df(oracle_df):
    # -------------------------------------------
    # write df to directory as .csv

    email_addr = conn_oracle.oracle_ntid + '@company.com' #change co name
    file_loc = '/home/kemri/ADW_Data/'
    filename = 'oracle_output_' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + ".csv"
    oracle_df.to_csv(file_loc + filename, index=False)
    subprocess.call('/home/kemri/kython/send_file.sh {} {} {}'.format(
        file_loc + filename, filename, email_addr), shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn_oracle()
```